# Finding an orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $c_{1}, c_{2}$ be nonzero real numbers and $U$ be the line of equations $c_{1}x_{1}=c_{2}x_{2}$. Find (describe by an equation, equations or in terms of x and y) the orthogonal complement of $U$ with respect to the standard dot product. What does this complement represent geometrically?

**EDIT:**
added a full problem similar to the one I am working on for context.

I am especially confused by the wording "line of equations". Does this mean that the equation describes a line and U is all points on that line?

Comment: By "translate this to set-builder notation," do you mean "write the solution set in set-builder notation"? If so, the answer is $\{(x_1,x_2):c_1x_1=c_2x_2\}$. I am not sure I understand the question in your title or its relevance to the question in the body.

Comment: Well, I assume $U$ must be a set or vector space of some sort, which I am used to seeing in set builder notation, not "U is the line of equations". I was asking how to take it from a "line of equations" to what I have seen more often, which is set builder notation.

Comment: Perhaps instead of bits and pieces you can provide the original context in full.

Comment: You can't really put equations themselves in set-builder notation. Could you give an example of what it is you're looking for?

Comment: @arctictern I included a full problem with different equations and dimension than the one I am working on. It's for an assignment, so I was trying to be a little vague in order to make sure I do the brunt of the work myself.

Comment: The phrase "line of equations" sounds like a typo. One might say "let $U$ be the line defined by the equation $c_1x_1=c_2x_2$" to make sense.

Comment: I think I found my answer here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232695/how-to-find-the-orthogonal-complement-of-a-subspace... should I delete my question?